# SQL Server create database user when user register

Tags: sql-server

I have a simple logic question which I don't understand for now. I am currently working on a simple winforms application which should allow users to register and login to a database (SQL Server database). That users should be able to, for example, buy something. Now I wonder If I need to create a database user which is allowed to modify that record to change their data or if there is another possibility to do that. I think most people create a table which stores all users and their information but how do they connect to the database if they are not a database user? Im a bit confused and I am pretty new to databases.

Comment: Your application has a login/user; not the person using the application.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341271/should-application-users-be-database-users

Comment: I recommend creating a database user for the application itself, so you can manage the privileges of that user and users register to you application using application log-ins but all database modifications go through the application DB account. If that makes sense?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint Ah okay I understand. But when I login as administrator I want a different behavior. For example the administrator should be able to delete users and he should also be able to do that within the application.